# Dagger 2. Не работает @Singelton, возвращает 2 объекта

Tags: android, dagger2

Здравствуйте, есть ProjectComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { ProjectModule.class})
public interface ProjectComponent extends ProjectDependency {

    void inject(ProjectApplication projectApplication);

    final class Initializer {
        public static ProjectComponent init(ProjectApplication application) {
            return DaggerProjectComponent.builder()
                    .projectModule(new ProjectModule(application))
                    .debugRetrofitModule(new DebugRetrofitModule())
                    .sharedPreferencesModule(new SharedPreferencesModule())
                    .toolModule(new ToolModule())
                    .build();
        }
        private Initializer() {} // No instances.
    }


}
```

В ProjectModule провайдится TaskSyncBus:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
TaskSyncBus provideTaskSyncBus() {
    return new TaskSyncBus();
}
```

Проблема в том что этот метод дергается дважды, возвращая два разных инстанса, в TaskRepository(он создается первым):

```
@Inject
public TaskRepository(TaskSyncBus taskSyncBus) {
    this.taskSyncBus = taskSyncBus;
}
```

и в TaskSyncAdapter он создается уже после и снова дергает метод `provideTaskSyncBus()` возвращая другой объект.

```
@Inject
public TaskSyncAdapter(TaskSyncBus taskSyncBus, Context context, @Named(SyncComponent.AUTOINIT) boolean autoInitialize) {
    super(context, autoInitialize);
    this.taskSyncBus = taskSyncBus;
}
```

В чем причина такого поведения и как это можно исправить?

Стоит отметить что TaskSyncAdapter - это SyncAdapter, который создается в :sync процесс.

Comment: А где вы инициализируете ProjectComponent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При старте сервиса в другом процессе создается ещё один экземпляр Application, в котором происходит инициализация ProjectComponent. Проблема тут не в dagger.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь чатику Dagger 2 в telegram: https://t.me/dagger_2